# Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

Tags: r, ggplot2

Pretty new to R. Trying to create a bar graph using ggplot2 to compare the type of 2016 primary election and Bernie Sanders's respective percentage of votes in that election.

I have:

```
y = $ Type : Factor w/ 2 levels "Caucus","Primary": 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
and x = $ SandersPercent : num  0.274 0.69 0.198 0.797 0.409 ...
```

I run:

```
geom_bar(Primary2016, aes(SandersPercent, Type))
```

and get:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

Sorry for such a dumb question. I've tried searching around and for some reason am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say it, but i can't believe that you have searched around — it is a quite rudimentary mistake you are making. I would suggest that you check out this brilliant resource for learning ggplot and friends: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/. As for your question, the problem is that you are only calling `geom_bar()`, instead your code should look like this:

```
ggplot(Primary2016, aes(SandersPercent, Type)) +
  geom_bar()
```